# MongoDB aggregate $elemMatch - Search in Array of Objects an ObjectId of a variable

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I've been trying for a while to search in **Array** composed of **Objects**, an **ObjectId** that is stored in a **Variable**. And this, via a **$elemMatch**, because I have several additional conditions.

This is a simplified example, so that everyone understands the problem.
Here is the test data:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('b00000000000000000000101'),
    friends: [
        {
            friend: ObjectId("b00000000000000000000201"),
            level: 5
        },
        {
            friend: ObjectId("b00000000000000000000202"),
            level: 3
        },
        {
            friend: ObjectId("b00000000000000000000203"),
            level: 8
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is the query that does **not work**:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            __testFriend: ObjectId("b00000000000000000000202"),
        },
    },
    {
        $match: {
            friends: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    friend: '$__testFriend',
                    level: { $gte: 3 },
                },
            },
        },
    },
]);
```

And here is the same query that **works** without the **variable**, with a hard ObjectId:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            __testFriend: ObjectId("b00000000000000000000202"),
        },
    },
    {
        $match: {
            friends: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    friend: ObjectId("b00000000000000000000202"),
                    level: { $gte: 3 },
                },
            },
        },
    },
]);
```

Can someone explain to me how to make my query work with variable `$__testFriend`?

Thank you !

Comment: You should use `$addFields` after the `$match` stage.

Comment: The variable `__testFriend` is an example, the real script use `lookup` before, which retrieves data from everywhere. The `$addFields` simply adds a final variable as a test.

Comment: Could you explain whole scenario by posting the sample documents

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible, anyway, whatever the source of the previous data, the concern of the variable is the same.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator in your $match:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            __testFriend: ObjectId("b00000000000000000000202")
        },
    },
    {
        $match: { $expr: {
            $gt: [ { $size: { $filter: {
                   input: "$friends",
                   as: "one",
                   cond: { $and: [ 
                       { $eq: [ "$$one.friend", "$__testFriend" ] },
                       { $gte: [ "$$one.level", 3 ] }
                   ] }
                } } },
                0
            ] }
        },
    },
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm looking around the weekend to see if it works with my system internally (because I want to use it in a `pipeline` of a `$lookup`). In any case, the query works perfectly with my example, thank you. I find it a pity that Mongo does not work directly with the variable...